# Interpreting results of matrix transform

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometric-interpretation

This is my first post on Mathematics Exchange, so I hope you'll be easy on me!

I'm trying to project points in one 2-d coordinate space into another 2-d coordinate space using a simple matrix transform ([Python/Numpy code here](https://gist.github.com/duhaime/384b26d9665a65f67ce405c3ad43ff51)).

By solving the matrix problem in the way indicated in that snippet, I get a 3x3 matrix. I now wish to use that matrix to project 2d points from the input space to the output space (lines 129-140 of the code).

My trouble is, given a 2d point in the input coordinates like 0, 347.04001, when I compose the point in 3x1 notation [0, 347.04001, 1] and multiply the point by my translation matrix, the point is not correctly positioned in the output space.

My question is: After I translate my input point to the output space (e.g. line 129), how should I interpret the third value of the output vector (row 3 column 1 of the output vector)? More generally, how should I interpret the values in the third row of the translation matrix? Any help others can provide on this question will be tremendously appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the third row of the projected points means, and it solves this riddle!

[This Wolfram's Mathword article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HomogeneousCoordinates.html) discusses the homogenous coordinate system, which I'm using in the the script linked above to represent my 2d points. That article states:

```
Homogeneous coordinates (x_1,x_2,x_3) of a finite point (x,y) 
in the plane are any three numbers for which

 (x_1)/(x_3)=x  
 (x_2)/(x_3)=y
```

That is to say, after projecting each of my points in lines 129-143, I receive as output a 3x1 vector such as the following (which is the result of the projection for the bottom left point):

```
[41.284498]
[-72.910514]
[0.999518]
```

I mistakenly thought this was an incorrect mapping to the desired lat, long coordinates for the bottom left, which are 41.3044, -72.9456. As the Wolfram's article states, however, I need to calculate x by using x1/x3 (`41.284498/0.999518`) and calculate y by using x2/x3 (`-72.910514 / 0.999518`), which yields the expected projection: 41.3044, -72.9456!